# Вывод текста из json массива

Tags: php, json

Помогите, пожалуйста, вывести текст из json файла:

```
var_dump($news);

string(188994) "{
"Новости":{
    "Новость":{
        "Категория":"Первая",
        "Дата":"Сегодня"
    } }
```

Как мне вывести текст, из каждого массива примерно так? `echo $news['Категория'];`

Comment: А где у Вас тут массив?

Comment: Начните с декодирования строки в массив.

Comment: а Вы можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: кириллица зло, тем более как key

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
$news = json_decode($news);
echo $news["Новости"]["Новость"]["Категория"];
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, но как вывести все $news["Новости"]["Новость"]["Категория"] ?

Comment: Вывожу foreach($news as $new){ print_r($new);} Такое чувство, что после json_decode(), в массив попадает только первый элемент.

Comment: для того, чтобы на выходе `json_decode` был ассоциативный массив, нужно передавать в функцию второй аргумент: `json_decode($news, true)`

Comment: Так и делал, но только одна новость попадает в массив: 
Array ( [Новости] => Array ( [Новость] => Array ( [Категория] => Первая [Дата] => Сегодня ) ) )

Comment: @user188252 а чего вы собственно хотели? `Новости` это **объект** а не массив.